# The div counter in each container separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Help please finish the code. I need to count the number of .resp-containers in each container separately. And then so that you can scroll this number in the switch and distribute the corresponding class to each element in the containers
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VXpZjP

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var getLength = $(".resp-container").length
    var item = $(".resp-container");
    switch (getLength) {
    case 1: item.addClass("full-resp");
    break;
    case 2: item.addClass("half-resp");
    break;
    case 3: item.addClass("third-resp");
    break;
    case 4: item.addClass("fourth-resp");
    break;
    default: item.addClass("fourth-resp"); 
}
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i´m sorry, what does *scroll this number in the switch and distribute the corresponding class to each element in the containers* mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.each()` for this, check snippet below....

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".container").each(function(){
    var getLength = $(this).find('.resp-container').length;
    
    var item = $(this).find('.resp-container');
switch (getLength) {
  case 1: item.addClass("full-resp");
    break;
  case 2: item.addClass("half-resp");
    break;
  case 3: item.addClass("third-resp");
    break;
  case 4: item.addClass("fourth-resp");
    break;
  default: item.addClass("fourth-resp"); 
}
  })
  
 
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.resp-container {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Респонсив классы */
.full-resp {
  width: 100%;
}
.half-resp {
  width: 50%;
}
.third-resp {
  width: 33%;
}
.fourth-resp {
  width: 25%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 780px){
  .half-resp, .third-resp, .fourth-resp {
  width: 50%;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 661px){
  .half-resp, .third-resp, .fourth-resp {
  width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For that you could use CSS instead, way more efficient than running a script

Stack snippet

```css
.resp-container:first-child:last-child {
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
}

.resp-container:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
.resp-container:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ .resp-container  {
  width: calc(50% - 15px);
}

.resp-container:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
.resp-container:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ .resp-container  {
  width: calc(33.333% - 15px);
}

.resp-container:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
.resp-container:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ .resp-container  {
  width: calc(25% - 15px);
}

/*  for this demo  */
.resp-container {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the need of the :first-child ? am i missing something trivial :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif When _both_ `:first-child` _and_ `nth-last-child(n)` match the same element the rule kicks, so when e.g. there is only 2 items, the _first-child_ will also be the _2nd last_ ... does it make sense?

Comment: ok but why not flex:1 to all the element and no need to all this ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif That will of course produce the same result when using Flexbox. Here I wanted to show how it could be done even w/o Flexbox.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Changed to `inline-block` to show how it works w/o Flexbox

Comment: ok got it but the OP is also modifing his Pen with your code so i got confused why all these

Comment: @TemaniAfif Mostly to not have to go all about what `flex: 1` does and mean, but also to show how one can count with CSS, which is less known.

Answer (score 1):

Why not a CSS easy solution without the need of complicating with jQuery or extra class:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.resp-container {
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just learned a lot of jQuery answering your question, but here it is:

Using `.each()`, `$(HTMLElement)` to make `this` back into a jQuery object and `.children()` to find the `resp-container` you want to count.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var container = $(".container");
  container.each(function() {
    var items = $(this).children(".resp-container");
    switch (items.length) {
      case 1:
        items.addClass("full-resp");
        break;
      case 2:
        items.addClass("half-resp");
        break;
      case 3:
        items.addClass("third-resp");
        break;
      case 4:
        items.addClass("fourth-resp");
        break;
      default:
        items.addClass("fourth-resp");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="resp-container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try vanilla JS, not jQuery:

```
const classes = ['full-resp', 'half-resp', 'third-resp', 'fourth-resp'] // array of classes that you want to add to the elements
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container'); // nodelist of all .container divs

containers.forEach(container => {
    // for each container...
    const respContainers = container.querySelectorAll('.resp-container'); // ... get nodelist of child .resp-container divs
    respContainers.forEach((rContainer, index) => {
        if (index < classes.length) return rContainer.classList.add(classes[index]);
        rContainer.classList.add(classes[classes.length - 1]); // if the index of the .resp-container div is larger than number of classes defined in classes array, add the last defined class to this element
    })
})
```